# "Коту дали молока" - Родительный или винительный падеж

Tags: грамматика, родительный-или-винительный

В предложении "Коту дали молока" в каком падеже слово " молока". Учитель считает, что в винительном падеже, так как предложение содержит только сказуемое.

Answer (score 6):

Если он так действительно думает, то он неправ. Это родительный падеж. Винительный падеж от слова "молоко" совпадает с именительным. Вообще падеж определяется ***постановкой вопроса*** (*дали чего? - молока*) и соответствующей ***флексией*** (окончанием) слова. Винительный падеж отвечал бы на вопрос "*дали что?*" и имел бы форму *"дали молоко"*.

Все разговоры насчет "только сказуемого" вообще не имеют никакого отношения к определению падежной формы. Тем более что тут это весьма сомнительная трактовка, по всем школьным правилам *"молока"* - дополнение.

Остается надеется, что вы не так поняли учителя.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы выявить здесь родительный падеж, достаточно просклонять в письменном виде слово "молоко" и увидеть слово из предложения в строке этого падежа.

Если же речь шла о том, в какой падеж поставить это слово при составлении предложения, то и тогда аргументация "есть только сказуемое" не действует: добавление подлежащего ничего не меняет ("Неопределённые лица дали коту молока/молоко" - оба варианта возможны). Винительный падеж логичнее аргументировать тем, что глагол "дать" - переходный и требует прямого дополнения, однако здесь такое дополнение, выражающее меру (порция, миска, некоторое количество) и косвенно управляющее родительным падежом имеющегося слова, может быть опущено. Это и делает возможным вариант "молока" в случае неопределённости его происхождения; винительный же падеж (молоко) соответствует большей определённости (о молоке, которое упоминалось, было кем-то налито и где-то стояло).

Comment: *Чтобы выявить здесь родительный падеж, достаточно просклонять в письменном виде слово "молоко" и увидеть слово из предложения в строке этого падежа.* - По-моему это уже перебор. Да еще в письменном виде. Неужели проще нельзя?))))

Comment: Кстати. *Если же речь шла о том, в какой падеж поставить это слово при составлении предложения, то и тогда аргументация "есть только сказуемое" не действует* - А когда она вообще действует? По-моему это вообще что-то марсианское. Есть только одна идея, откуда у такой нелепости могут ноги расти, но это совсе не то, о чем вы (и я) тут говорили.

Comment: Скорее, всего, "она" никогда не действует, но вдруг оппонент где-то такое правило прочитал? :)

Answer (score 2):

Забавная ситуация... Я тоже не думаю, что сколько-нибудь адекватный учитель мог что-то подобное воспроизвести. Поэтому предполагаю следующее.

Обсуждалось, какой падеж, *именительный или винительный*, у слова *молоко* во фразе "Коту дали молоко". Учитель сказал, что тут нет подлежащего, одно только сказуемое, а следовательно именительного падежа быть не может. В современных терминах "сказуемое" в односоставных предложениях не выделяют, называя его "единственным главным членом", но учитель мог быть старой закалки - и это в общем-то не ошибка. По сути учитель сказал верную вещь. 
Для демонстрации этого факта учитель, видимо, предложил изменить "молоко" на "молока", появился родительный падеж, и уж он-тот никак не мог быть спутан с именительным.

В результате "испорченного телефона" все перепуталось, как в дурном анекдоте. Вспомогательная фраза стала основной, вопрос "именительный или винительный" превратился в "родительный или винительный", а логика учителя пополнилась словом "поэтому", что привело к появлению совершенно невероятного силлогизма "один член, *поэтому* винительный". Это не совсем верно даже исходной фразы   (не "поэтому", а "следовательно" - ведь здесь речь не о исходных фактах, а о рассуждениях), но в случае с родительным падежом ("дали молока") получился просто какой-то сюжет для театра абсурда.

Я не уверен, что все было именно так, но по крайней мере так могло быть. По-иному же объяснить всю ситуацию трудно.

Comment: Ну да. Я примерно о чем-то таком и подумал, но в моих правилах отвечать именно на тот вопрос, который задан - и именно как он задан. А вашей версии получается, что  реально надо было все с ног на голову поставить, формулируя вопрос. Я как-то побоялся думать, что такое возможно...

Answer (score 1):

Мы дали коту молока. - Коту дали молока. **Падеж (родительный)  не изменился в двусоставном предложении.**

Р.п. в данном случае указывает **на часть продукта.** Сравнить: дай мне **молоко** (всё имеющееся, В.п.) - дай мне **молока** (часть из того, что есть, Р.п.).